# "upgrade" from ubuntu 15.10 to ubuntu GNOME 15.10

Tags: unity, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

**Is it possible to keep my personal files and reinstall the system around them?**

I understand that I can just install all of the gnome shell packages and whatnot without having to reinstall, but I am feeling lazy.

Last time I tried to install gnome shell over 15.10, ubuntu wouldn't boot (but I am sure that was my fault).  Any thoughts on this?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: It'll be _way_ way easier and will take _much_ less effort to just install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and login to it instead.

Comment: I did that with my last install and ran into a WORLD of hurt as ubuntu wouldn't boot because of some rogue dependency that clashed with previously installed thing.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The installation worked fine for me the five times I did it on 15,10 and the three times I did it on 14.04, so it seems you ran into your unlucky install right away instead of a few installs in.

Comment: Just my luck, I suppose.  Thanks again dude, im gonna try again right now :)

Comment: Good luck, don't kill it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes. As long as you don't reformat the partition containing `/home`, a reinstall should leave your files alone.

However, as noted in Zacharee1's comment, it's almost certainly better to just

```
apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```